# SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER) Process using high memory

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

We have the Reporting Services installed on our database but we are not actually using it. Generally, the running process takes up a few MB but all of a sudden it has jumped to 4GB. We have restarted the process but it immediately jumps to 4 GB.

I ran the below query but the results are empty

```
Use  ReportServer
 Go

select * 
from ExecutionLog2 
order by TimeStart DESC
```

What could we do to help identify what is happening with this process?

For context, we are running the 2012 BI edition

Comment: If you're not using it, why not just disable it?

Comment: I have now although I am concerned there is a dependency I am unaware of. It has been running benignly for a while and I’m concerned this is a symptom of a larger problem so I am trying to trace the root cause of the memory spike

Comment: What counter/tool are you using to track the memory usage?

Comment: I generally just capture via system performance monitor

Comment: What specific counters are you tracking and what do they report?